# Android layout chat like listview

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to make a chat-like view using a list view in which the messages are displayed left and right.
The markup for the left message is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="left">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MessageListItemText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="@drawable/RoundedCornersBlue"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="realy long realy long realy long realy long realy long realy long realy long realy long "
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MessageListItemDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="#cbc4b1"
        android:text="23:11"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

but the second textview (the TimeStamp) is missing.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxDXQ.jpg

The Right message has the following markup

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="right">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MessageListItemDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="#cbc4b1"
        android:text="12:34"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MessageListItemText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="realy long realy long realy long realy long realy long realy long realy long realy long "
        android:background="@drawable/RoundedCornersBlue"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MnyW.jpg

This one looks as I want it too.
The only difference between left and right is the android:gravity of the LinearLayout and the order of the textviews in the LinearLayout.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?
Or how could I achieve this type of design

Thank you,
Mihai

Comment: (not relevant to the question, but still) the gravity of your linearlayout is ignored, because the layout is horizontal. only vertical-related gravity can be used. (and vice-versa, horizontal gravities for vertical orientation)

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the exact same problem recently. Although you looked for an answer a while ago, it might come in handy for others. Here's how I dealt with it :

This is the xml code for my conversation_item, by default everything stands on the left :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/conversationItemRelativeLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="11dp"
                android:paddingRight="11dp"
                >

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/conversationUserImage"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/my_ears_placeholder_grey_background"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/conversationBubble"
            />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/conversationDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Time Ago"
            android:layout_below="@id/conversationUserImage"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

            />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/conversationBubble"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/conversationUserImage"
            android:text="Exemple Text"
            android:background="@drawable/bubbleleft"
            android:gravity="center"
            />

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/messagePicture"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/conversationUserImage"
            android:gravity="center"
            />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then instead of duplicating xmls, I set the layout changes in code, with a method called by my custom adapter :

```
private View getConversationItem(Message message) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(ConversationActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.conversation_item, null);
        ...

        if (message.iAmOwner()) {          
                conversationBubble.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bubbleleft));
                messagePicture.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bubbleleft));                               
                ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(myPictureURL, conversationUserImage, options);
                ...
        }
        else {    
                ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(senderPictureURL, conversationUserImage, options);
                conversationBubble.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bubbleright));
                messagePicture.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bubbleright));


            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams conversationUserImageParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)       conversationUserImage.getLayoutParams();
            conversationUserImageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            conversationUserImage.setLayoutParams(conversationUserImageParams);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams conversationDateParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)conversationDate.getLayoutParams();
            conversationDateParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            conversationDate.setLayoutParams(conversationDateParams);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams conversationBubbleParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) conversationBubble.getLayoutParams();
            conversationBubbleParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF,R.id.conversationUserImage);


            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams messagePictureParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) messagePicture.getLayoutParams();
            messagePictureParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF,R.id.conversationUserImage);

            messagePictureParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF);
            conversationBubbleParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF);

            conversationBubble.setLayoutParams(conversationBubbleParams);
            messagePicture.setLayoutParams(messagePictureParams);

        }

        return view;
    }
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: I am now switching to a two xml approach, as any modification in the xml would require to modify the code. It started being troublesome as I added some more details to the xml. I am quite unsure about the performance issues it could raise, but it'll be much easier to manage in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create two different xml for chat. you can achieve this in single.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtsenderdt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
            android:text="07:03"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtsender"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="@drawable/chat1"
            android:text="realy long realy long realy long realy long realy long realy long realy long realy long realy long realy long realy long realy long realy long realy long realy long realy long"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't really answer my question. I want to add a time stamp next to the message: for the left message the time stamp needs to be right of the message, for the right message it's the other way around

Comment: i have updated my answer.check this and let me know,if is there any problem

Comment: Doesn't help. What happens if you add a really long text? Plus, my design done using different layouts for messages

Comment: ohhh i see so you need to adjust both layouts.

Comment: No :). I just one a text message with a time stamp right next to it, regardless of the size of the message

Comment: Try and add the time stamp to the right of the message. The message will overflow over the time stamp

Comment: I've reached the result I want using setMaxWidth(), but I would rather do it from markup. Just don't know if that's possible. Thank you for our help :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `LinearLayout` with `orientation="horizontal"` first `TextView` in message left fills all available space.
So you have to change `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout` like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="left">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MessageListItemDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="#cbc4b1"
        android:text="23:11"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MessageListItemText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/MessageListItemDate"
        android:background="@drawable/RoundedCornersBlue"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="realy long realy long realy long realy long realy long realy long realy long realy long "
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it works only with long text. Try adding a short text. It will align to the right instead of left

Comment: I want the time stamp to always be right next to the message, regardless if it's a short or long message

Comment: Ok, replace `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` by `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` in `MessageListItemText`

Comment: That won't work either. I've achieved this using setMaxWidth(), but after that I decided to go with the time stamp below the message text inside the same bubble. Thanks for your help :)